# How to wait for Stripe API call to return before validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am integrating Stripe with Devise. I want to sign a user up with stripe and store that Stripe ID before the user is saved. The method is completing before the API call return the Customer hash. How can I fix this?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :stripe_id
    before_validation :create_stripe_customer

    def create_stripe_customer
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
           :email => email,
           :card  => stripe_card_token
         )
        self.stripe_id = customer.id
     end
end
```

When I inspect the User, stripe_id is nil, and validation fails.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve this is to wrap it with a protective block using `Active Record Transaction`.

> Transactions are protective blocks where SQL statements are only permanent if they can all succeed as one atomic action.

```
begin
  @user = User.new(strong_params)

  User.transaction do
    @user.save!

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
              :email => email,
              :card  => stripe_card_token
            )

    @user.update_attributes!(stripe_id: customer.id)
  end
rescue Exception => ex
    flash[:danger] = "#{ex}"
    render 'new'
end
```

This will enforce that the statement will be executed together or not at all.